# Upload a file into Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using angular 4 in client side and written nodejs & express services with MongoDB to upload a file into the server .Here in my angular side i am using the code `<input type="file" id="myfile" />` and sending the path of the file to the server for uploading that file into server i am using `document.getElementById("myid")`.value; to get the path of the file but it gives me the path as `C:/fakepath/myfilename.txt` but for uploading the file i need the correct path not the fakepath. I have searched in google they are saying the true path is disabled by the modern browser for some security reason, Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: no, you dont need the path.

Comment: Convert image in base64 string format using angular and send it to server .In response get the path of your system where the image stored

Comment: I am not storing image i am storing any kind of file

Answer (score 0):

The point of a file input is to *send the file* to the server. That is your "workaround".

The file path is useless to you: It is the path on the visitors computer which your server can't access.

Just upload the file normally.

Comment: You mean just convert the file into byte streams and store it in server?